# controls are overlap when screen size small

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, user-interface

In my application i had used `tablelayoutpanel`,`dock` and `anchor` for the visual representation of the form. Additionaly i calculated the fontsize of the forms according to the screen resolution. Its runs perfectly in monitors which is having size more than 17 inches but if screen size is getting below, its not working properly. controls are over lapped and some times controls are partially displayed. why? and what may be the solution for this problem.?

Comment: Well, this is pretty obvious, you can't cram a bunch of controls on a postage stamp.  Set the form's AutoScroll property to True and set the MinimumSize property to the smallest size where overlap doesn't occur so it is still usable on a small screen.

Comment: @HansPassant My boss wanted me to display the forms without scroll bar.And he insisting me to change the size of each controls inside the form according to the pixels being used by the current resolution. Is he suggested a right way.? your comment or answer will be valuable in this occation. thanks.

Comment: You'd better do what he asks for I guess.  He's the boss, it doesn't matter if he's right or wrong.  Use the form's Resize event.

Comment: @HansPassant I guess, resizing each controls inside the forms will not be an efficient way. i wont prefer wrong way for $. :) Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Be prepared for your boss to change his mind when he sees what this will actually look like.

Answer (score 0):

Scale your form. I haven't really used it, but I noticed inconsistent behaviour. Like, if you scale your form with all child controls by 50%, then scale it by 200%, you will not get back to the original form... at least not for all the child controls. Play around with it, maybe you will be able to solve the inconsistency.

```
        Dim size As System.Drawing.SizeF
        Dim scalePercent As Long
        scalePercent = 50 ' scale the form and all child controls by a percentage
        size.Height = scalePercent / 100
        size.Width = scalePercent / 100
        Me.Scale(size)
```